# Paying import taxes in different EU country than my home

Tags: shopping

I have ordered goods from U.S. to France. I know I will have to pay the VAT and I'm ok with this. My concern is the following:

I'm a long-term visitor of France, I'm a citizen of Czech Republic. Does it make any difference? Where I have to pay the tax? How is such a package delivered?

I suppose I'll get a "voucher" in the post box and I'll have to go somewhere (to a Tax Office / Post Office ... ?). However, I'd like to know the details so that I know what to be prepared for.

Comment: The fact that you don't live on a permanent basis in France means that you must have travelled there. Hence the question could be on topic here ...

Comment: @MarcelC. You could move this to [Meta](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/) but this question is not travel related as per [FAQ](http://travel.stackexchange.com/faq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sweden where I am then answer is that you pay the VAT (and if needed import duty) in Sweden, and it is the postal service that manages that process so you just get a voucher in the mail asking you to prove the value of the item and a description of what it is, and then you get a new voucher when this is done with details on how much to pay.

Looking [here](http://www.dutycalculator.com/help_center/Import-duty-taxes-when-importing-into-France/) it seems like the same deal. The important part for paying duty is importing into the country.

If you know french then the [French Customs](http://www.douane.gouv.fr/) website might even be better than the first link.